# Reporting Results from a Mixed ANOVA

Tags: anova, spss, model, mixed-model, effects

I have done a Mixed ANOVA on some data from a tennis serving experiment and am slightly confused on how to report the results. I am comparing the effect of self-talk (either instructional or motivational) on the service accuracy of tennis players who are either experienced or novices. Participants served and earned a points score, learned one type of self-talk, then served again for a points score.

SPSS has given me a statistically significant result between before/after serve scores and self-talk, but non-significant results between before/after serve scores and experience and before/after serve scores and experience and self-talk combined. Can you please advise on how I should report these results? Thanks a lot.